# signInWithCustomToken NOT GETTING RECOGNISED IN ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make custom authentication using username and password in android app.
After getting instance from Firebase I made token with name mCustomToken and pass it to the function signInWithCustomToken [as shown in documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth).
The error I am getting is that function signInWithCustomToken() is not getting recognised here and it is asking me to rename reference:(

Can someone please help me on how to solve this error?
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO1on.png

Dependencies in my gradle file looks like

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Do I need to add more dependencies?

[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Do you get any errors while building? Also are there any warnings when you hover on `signInWithCustomToken`?

Comment: yeah on hovering it shows
Cannot resolve method 'signInWithCustomToken' in 'FirebaseAuth'

Comment: Is it because I am implementing Admin side and client on same side???
If yes then how to differentiate them???

Comment: I was about to ask why do you have `createCustomToken` on client side. That method is supposed to be used using Admin SDK in a secure environment like Cloud functions or our servers. You should remove the Firebase Admin dependency.

Comment: I am using firebase so where should I write the code for generating token???

Comment: In a [Cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) or your server. But which authentication method are you trying to add in your app?  Custom Token auth is mostly used when you have legacy authentication system or database containing all users' credentials.

Comment: I am using username+password for authentication
Would u mind sharing ur email, so that I can share my apk file

Comment: Can you provide more information on where are you storing the username and passwords and how have you to implemented it? Because Firebase has no username-password auth natively.

Comment: I am storing username and password in Realtime Firebase Database.

Comment: How can I send u the apk file so that u can get the whole thing???

Comment: Please show us the code where you say *signInWithCustomToken() is not getting recognised*.  Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo you can see the code in above given image-link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO1on.png

Comment: Please also edit your question and show us how `mAuth` object is defined.

Comment: FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

Comment: @AlexMamo
If I remove admin dependency then it is not showing error but then createCustomToken() doesn't get recognise